# "Pythonic" way of replacing one or more items in a list, in-place

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to replace one or more items in a list, in place. My gut reaction would be something like this:

```
mylist = [...]
other_object = dict(spam='eggs', a_list=mylist)

def replacer(item):
   ... contents not shown, returns a replacement ...

mylist[:] = [replacer(item) for item in mylist]
```

It needs to be in-place, so that if I have other objects (e.g. `other_object` in the above example) with a reference to mylist, then those other objects will see the updated value. (Clarification: I do **not** want to require any changes to `other_object` because it is managed elsewhere from the code I maintain.)

Is this the most idiomatic way to do it in Python? If not, is there a better way?

Comment: The idiomatic way would be to not do it in place but instead return a new object that you can pass to things that care about it

Comment: no, that's the *functional* way, rather than idiomatic, which I would love to do, but I can't in this case.

Comment: mylist = [replacer(item) for item in mylist]

Comment: What about defining a very minimal `class` wrapper for a list? You could then run a method like `mylist.replace(function=replacer)` and change the `self.lst` attribute accordingly.

Comment: Seems idiomatic enough, but if the list is large and you only want to update some items, why mutate everything? That would seem to work against the main advantage of an in-place change (more memory efficient). Just replace the items you need to replace.

Comment: How 'bout `[mylist.__setitem__(i, replacer(item)) for i, item in enumerate(mylist)]`?

Comment: @fedeisas well better not in a list comp, then ☺

Comment: @zmo you're right. But worst case you'll end up with a list full of `None` not assigned anywhere, hahah.

Comment: @fedeisas, the OP asked for *pythonic*. What you've shown would be some beautiful ruby 

Comment: What is wrong with `other_object['eggs'][:]=[replacer(item) for item in other_object['eggs']]`?

Comment: @dawg see my latest clarification -- I manage `mylist` but it is referenced in other objects I don't have control over.

Comment: If you change `mylist` un place it will change `mylist` everywhere...

Comment: @dawg that is exactly what I want!

Comment: See my example below. Note that you need to be careful because other processes can change the references to `mylist` if you do not have full control of the objects in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, your own solution sounds pretty fine to me:

```
mylist[:] = [replacer(item) for item in mylist]
```

or you can do it in a more explicit but verbose way:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[idx] = replacer(val)
```

I can imagine many other ways, but I would be burnt and banned to hell if I suggest them

---

Demonstrating that `other_object` sees the change:

```
>>> def replacer(x):
...     return x+2
... 
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> other_object = dict(spam='eggs', a_list=mylist)
>>> mylist[:] = [replacer(item) for item in mylist]
>>> mylist, other_object['a_list']
([3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5])
```

you're welcome ♥

Comment: Neither of these approaches update `other_object`, like OP requested.

Comment: @not_a_robot These approaches mutate the list, the very list that `other_object` contains. The code doesn't have to touch `other_object` for the change to be reflected there.

Comment: @not_a_robot why do you say that?

Comment: Hmm... I defined a very minimal `replacer` function and tried both code sets and `mylist` was updated, obviously, but the list-value in the `other_object` dict remained the same.

Comment: `mylist=[1,2,3]; other_object=dict(spam='eggs', a_list=mylist); replacer = lambda x: x**2; mylist = [replacer(x) for x in mylist];` So really the only difference is the `mylist` versus `mylist[:]` assignment step... What's happening there?

Comment: @not_a_robot That's creating a new list and assigning it to the *name* `mylist`, not modifying the original list referenced by both `mylist` and `other_object['alist']`. You'll want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @chepner Ah, yes. So to reassign to the "original" list, I need the `[:]` syntax, apparently. Cheers, fellas, thanks.

Comment: @not_a_robot -- I can't update `other_object` directly.

Comment: @zmo which of your two approaches do you prefer? I've been trying to favor functional over imperative, but only if it makes the resulting code cleaner.

Comment: In Java I would use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which provides a means of replacing/removing items as they are iterated over.

Comment: @JasonS I'd say the second syntax is more explicit, even though a bit verbose, so I'd say it's the more pythonic way. @not_a_robot's reaction to the `my_list[:]` syntax is a good proof of that, be a bit tired and you'll miss the `[:]` part… Though if you really need an expression, or need a oneliner (for use in a lambda or something like that), don't hesitate to use the one liner!

Comment: When in doubt, always chose the most readable way, and if you're still hesitating reread the [pep-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly:

```
>>> my_list=[1,2,3]
>>> other_obj={'eggs':my_list}
>>> my_other_list=[[1,2,3],my_list]
>>> other_obj['eggs'][:]=[e+2 for e in other_obj['eggs']]
>>> other_obj
{'eggs': [3, 4, 5]}
>>> my_other_list
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> my_list
[3, 4, 5]
```

Notice that anywhere the original `my_list` is used, it is changed by using a slice assignment to any one of those names:

```
>>> my_other_list[1][:]=[20,30,40]
>>> my_list
[20, 30, 40]
>>> other_obj
{'eggs': [20, 30, 40]}
```

More at Ned Batchelder: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

---

Based on your edit: Just change `mylist` inplace and it will change in the other objects where `mylist` is used (but not a copy of `mylist`). You can use any method that does in place modification.

Example:

```
>>> my_list[:]=['new','inserted','items']
```

The other two objects change too:

```
>>> other_obj
{'eggs': ['new', 'inserted', 'items']}
>>> my_other_list
[[1, 2, 3], ['new', 'inserted', 'items']]
```

Just beware if these are 'shared' objects since other programs / processes can change the name reference without your knowledge. Potentially sneaky bugs.